# How to create a CMIS Server

Tags: java, .net, server, cmis

The company i work for needs to validate/certificate all stored PDF files and save different versions of the PDF's.
and so i am trying to make our file system/logic be CMIS compliable, because the validation is going to be made by a third party.
The filing logic we have now is based on paths + GUID, these values are saved in a data base. Then we have a couple of WS that get and set the PDF.

i am a .net Visual studio guy, and the tutorial in OpenCMIS Server Development Guide - 2nd Edition is for eclipse and I cannot get it to work. 
is there any other CMIS server tutorial? it would be better if it was in .net but I will be happy with any other tutorial.

Thanks
PS: I already have the NCMIS project.

Comment: "I cannot get it to work":  What does that mean? How can we help?

Comment: in the "OpenCMIS Server Development Guide" i got to "Setting up a Tomcat server target in Eclipse". again I am really don’t know much about apache or eclipse. I was thinking a video or something would help me. i never got the Connecting CMIS Workbench to our local server to work